# eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented when running CustomAdapter in Android

Tags: android

I trying to display my dropbox files with a `CustomAdapter`. Here is how I do it. When I click a button in my `mainActivity`, an intent get me to `List.java activity`. In this activity, I will run the my `CustomAdapter` here.

My problem is when I run the app, the list I created just display 1 first item. Then I get this line in the Android Monitor

```
W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented.
```

code:

```
public class List extends AppCompatActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_list);

    Bundle receivedBundle=this.getIntent().getExtras();

    String[] arrayList = receivedBundle.getStringArray("array");

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, arrayList, arrayList);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

Here is the `layout_list.xml` that this List.java display

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my `customAdapter.java` class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    String[] fileNameArray;
    String[] fileSizeArray;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] name, String[] size){
        this.fileNameArray = name;
        this.fileSizeArray = size;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        System.out.println(fileNameArray[0]);

        // then create an layout
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return fileNameArray.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_layout, null);

            TextView nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            TextView sizeTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sizeTextView);

            nameTextView.setText(fileNameArray[position]);
            sizeTextView.setText(fileSizeArray[position]);

            System.out.println("Position" + position);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

This is the `custom_list_layout.xml` file that my `customAdapter` use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sizeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameTextView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it in a full of sunny (but i don't like them) sunday. It has nothing to do with customAdapter, and genymotion, or activity. It is because the String[] array i use as parameters for my customAdapter is null.